# multiple CComboBox sharing the same data

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a MFC dialog with 32 CComboBoxes on it that all have the same data in the listbox.  Its taking a while to come up, and it looks like part of the delay is the time I need to spend using InsertString() to add all the data to the 32 controls.  How can I subclass CComboBox so that the 32 instances share the same data?

Comment: How many items are you adding to each of the ComboBoxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off window redrawing when filling the combos. e.g.:

```
m_wndCombo.SetRedraw(FALSE);
// Fill combo here
...
m_wndCombo.SetRedraw(TRUE);
m_wndCombo.Invalidate();
```

This might help.

Comment: I think you will need to make sure you call Invalidate after doing this.

Comment: Not if calling from WM_INITDIALOG IIRC, but well spotted.  :)

Comment: fixing the symptom but not answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is calling "InitStorage" to preallocate the internal memory for the strings.
From MSDN:

`// Initialize the storage of the combo box to be 256 strings with
// about 10 characters per string, performance improvement.`

int n = pmyComboBox->InitStorage(256, 10);

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been said, you might also turn off sorting in your combo box and presort the data before you insert it.

Answer (score 0):

One way along the lines of your request would be to go owner drawn - you will be writing a fair chunk of code, but you won't have to add the data to all of them.
"[CComboBox::DrawItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5hb5f9t.aspx)"

Support.microsoft have this article on subclassing a Combo box which might also be of interest
"[How to subclass CListBox and Cedit inside of CComboBox](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q174667)"

Really one has to ask if it is worth the effort, and alot of that depends things like

- number of entries in the list
- number of times the dialog will show
- variability of the combo content
- optomising elsewhere

  - not drawing until the screen is complete
  - only building the dialog once and re showing it.
  - using the one combo but showing it in different locations at different times